# Unchecking a class of checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

So I have this JQuery that intends to uncheck a particular class of checkbox:

```
$('.boringassclassname_class').prop('checked', false);
```

And I have this checkbox as requested by someone who needed an MVE:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="whocares" name="doesntmatter" class="boringassclassname_class">
```

I fire this inside another checkbox's onchange, and it does nothing.  The class of checkbox does not uncheck.  No exceptions.

This is jquery 1.8.3, so I shouldn't need to use attr for this.  I tried using

```
$('.boringassclassname_class').each(function() { ($this).prop('checked', false) })
```

but that threw errors that $this was undefined.  The class selector most certainly is not undefined, since show() and hide() work just fine on it.

I tried researching mass selectors and doers, but nothing in my searches came up that allowed it to apply to a class.  So how do I uncheck a class of checkbox?

Comment: Post a [mcve] to your question please. Also what do you mean by the class of the checkbox doesn't uncheck?

Comment: write as $('.{$id}_class').each(function() { $(this).prop('checked', false) })

Comment: I added your minimal, complete and verifiable example checkbox.  What I mean by the class of the checkbox doesn't uncheck is that there is a class of checkbox that is checked, and this function that is expected to uncheck the class of checkbox does not uncheck the class of checkbox.  Let me know if you need further explanation!
Checking $(this) instead of ($this).  Thank you!

Comment: Is that `{$id}` replaced by some kind of templating code? Because that's not a great class name...

Comment: It was a placeholder, I renamed it for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to use an each.  `prop()` does an implicit iteration over the result stack.

```js
$('.ARTReason_1_AbnormSpermParams_AzoospermiaObs_PriorVasectomy_class').prop('checked', false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="whocares" name="doesntmatter" class="ARTReason_1_AbnormSpermParams_AzoospermiaObs_PriorVasectomy_class" checked>
<input type="checkbox" id="whocares" name="doesntmatter" class="ARTReason_1_AbnormSpermParams_AzoospermiaObs_PriorVasectomy_class" checked> 
<input type="checkbox" id="whocares" name="doesntmatter" class="ARTReason_1_AbnormSpermParams_AzoospermiaObs_PriorVasectomy_class" checked>
```

Comment: @Kwahn so yeah, you don't need the each.  `prop()` does an implicit each over the result stack.

Comment: Updated my answer to use that exact class name.  Works fine. @Kwahn

Comment: that means that it's not my code that's wrong - IT'S THE SYSTEM!  I have a suspicion because of this, but it requires yelling at a system architect to extract the truth of the matter.  I shall solve this mystery posthaste.  You earned credit for helping me this far.

Answer (score 3):

write $(this) instead of ($this)

```
$('.{$id}_class').each(function() { $(this).prop('checked', false) })
```

Comment: Or just don't use jquery.  `this.checked = false`.  There's no need for jQuery with this property access.  Or just `$('.{$id}_class').prop('checked', false)` as the each is unnecessary.  prop will do an iterator already

Comment: Taplar, know what's funny?  If I ctrl+F the code  you typed, it actually picks up my non-functional code as an exact and identical match to yours!  

That makes me sad though. :(

Comment: So I tried this each iterator, and you were right - it was $(this) instead of ($this)!  however, despite hiding the checkbox working (independently to make sure hiding didn't break unchecking), unchecking it does not work. :(